# Como destacar/grifar palavras em texto?

Tags: javascript, html

### Buscando no Google, sobre como destacar e/ou grifar palavras em um texto

Encontrei um código que aplica este efeito chamado `highlight` nas palavras buscadas. Porém, quando fui testar o código, as palavras não estavam sendo destacadas, mas analisando o código não consegui encontrar o motivo do problema!

Segue o código abaixo:

```js
function doDestacaTexto(Texto, termoBusca) {

   /*******************************************************************/
   // CASO QUEIRA MODIFICAR O ESTILO DA MARCAÇÃO ALTERE ESSAS VARIÁVEIS
   /*******************************************************************/
   inicioTag = "<font style='color:#000;background-color:#A0FFFF'><b>";
   fimTag = "</b></font>";

   var novoTexto = "";
   var i = -1;
   var lcTermoBusca = termoBusca.toLowerCase();
   var lcTexto = Texto.toLowerCase();

   while (Texto.length > 0) {
      i = lcTexto.indexOf(lcTermoBusca, i + 1);
      if (i < 0) {
         novoTexto += Texto;
         Texto = "";
      } else {
         if (Texto.lastIndexOf(">", i) >= Texto.lastIndexOf("<", i)) {
            if (lcTexto.lastIndexOf("/script>", i) >= lcTexto.lastIndexOf("<script", i)) {
               novoTexto += Texto.substring(0, i) + inicioTag + Texto.substr(i, termoBusca.length) + fimTag;
               Texto = Texto.substr(i + termoBusca.length);
               lcTexto = Texto.toLowerCase();
               i = -1;
            }
         }
      }
   }
   return novoTexto;
}

function doDestacaTextoBusca(textoBusca, textoObj, ehFrase) {
   if (ehFrase) {
      arrayBusca = [textoBusca];
   } else {
      arrayBusca = textoBusca.split(" ");
   }

   var Texto = textoObj.innerHTML;

   for (var i = 0; i < arrayBusca.length; i++) {
      Texto = doDestacaTexto(Texto, arrayBusca[i]);
   }
   textoObj.innerHTML = Texto;
   return true;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Highlight de Textos igual ao Google</title>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" />
      <head>
         <script language="JavaScript" src="destacaTexto.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      Escolha a palavra: 
      <input type="text" value="codigo" size="25" name="busca">
      <input type="button" onClick="doDestacaTextoBusca(document.getElementById('busca').value, teste)" value="Destacar Texto"><br>
      <br />
      <div id="teste">
         Site para programadores com codigos fonte, noticias, video aulas, downloads, artigos e tutorias. Tudo sobre Web. ASP, PHP, .NET, JSP, ABAP, JavaScript, ActionScript DHTML, XHTML, CSS, Web Standards/Tableless, mySQL, SQL, Photoshop, Flash MX e muito mais.
         Utilize a palavra "codigo" como exemplo pois há neste texto muitas repetições de codigo, assim é possível ver a palavra codigo em destaque diversas vezes.
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

<sup>**Fonte**: https://www.codigofonte.com.br/codigos/efeito-hightlight-em-palavras-igual-ao-google</sup>

Comment: Não ficou claro, o que você gostaria de fazer?

Comment: Olá @Renan, alterei a pergunta inicial para melhor esclarecimento da minha dúvida.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar o [markjs](https://markjs.io/) para isto:

```js
// cria uma instância definindo o elemento onde será "marcada" as palavras.
var instance = new Mark(document.getElementById('source'))

function highlight(word){
  instance.unmark({
    done: function(){
      instance.mark(word)
    }
  })
}

document
  .getElementById('query')
  .addEventListener('input', function(){
    highlight(this.value)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/mark.js/8.6.0/mark.min.js"></script>

<input id='query' placeholder='Buscar por...' type='text'>

<div id='source' contenteditable>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis sollicitudin, purus ac tempus faucibus, dolor ligula tempus lectus, a vulputate dolor lorem at nibh. Praesent euismod metus ante. Maecenas sit amet magna eget mauris lobortis semper nec vel dolor. Maecenas at turpis vel lectus suscipit posuere sed id tortor. Sed tristique viverra dolor, vitae semper elit fermentum et. Quisque dignissim neque at molestie finibus. Mauris porttitor leo nec velit lacinia, sed gravida mi tincidunt. Donec hendrerit eros vel magna hendrerit faucibus.
Suspendisse eu iaculis neque. Nullam quam sem, maximus a nulla eu, gravida pellentesque ipsum. Duis tempus pretium enim, eu accumsan lorem ullamcorper id. Ut tristique risus leo, non venenatis neque facilisis a. Sed vel urna sit amet nisl posuere semper vel non purus. Sed tempus neque quis accumsan vehicula. Phasellus mollis mollis felis. Cras dignissim gravida elit, at aliquam metus lobortis ac. Aliquam ac dapibus justo. Vivamus porttitor commodo magna, ut cursus felis imperdiet id. Aenean placerat nisi vitae justo semper, sit amet tristique tellus tempor.
</div>
```

Se quiser formatar o *hightlight* (outras cores, etc) basta estilizar o elemento `mark` com CSS, inserindo as propriedades que preferir. O Markjs cria um elemento `<mark>` para cada match encontrado no elemento observado pela instância. Mais informações (precisão, *case sensitive*, filtros, etc) podem ser encontradas na [documentação do projeto](https://markjs.io/#api).

Um outro exemplo, exibindo o número *matches* dados no texto:

```js
// cria uma instância definindo o elemento onde será "marcada" as palavras.
const instance = new Mark(document.getElementById('source'))
const matches = document.getElementById('matches')

function highlight(word){
  instance.unmark({
    done: function(){
      instance.mark(word, {
        done: function(numberOfOccurrences){
          matches.innerHTML = numberOfOccurrences
        }
      })
    }
  })
}

document
  .getElementById('query')
  .addEventListener('input', function(){
    highlight(this.value)
})
```

```css
div { padding: 5px; margin-top: 2%; border: 1px solid #ccc }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/mark.js/8.6.0/mark.min.js"></script>

<input id='query' placeholder='Buscar por...' type='text'>
Matches: <span id='matches'>0</span>

<div id='source' contenteditable>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis sollicitudin, purus ac tempus faucibus, dolor ligula tempus lectus, a vulputate dolor lorem at nibh. Praesent euismod metus ante. Maecenas sit amet magna eget mauris lobortis semper nec vel dolor. Maecenas at turpis vel lectus suscipit posuere sed id tortor. Sed tristique viverra dolor, vitae semper elit fermentum et. Quisque dignissim neque at molestie finibus. Mauris porttitor leo nec velit lacinia, sed gravida mi tincidunt. Donec hendrerit eros vel magna hendrerit faucibus.
Suspendisse eu iaculis neque. Nullam quam sem, maximus a nulla eu, gravida pellentesque ipsum. Duis tempus pretium enim, eu accumsan lorem ullamcorper id. Ut tristique risus leo, non venenatis neque facilisis a. Sed vel urna sit amet nisl posuere semper vel non purus. Sed tempus neque quis accumsan vehicula. Phasellus mollis mollis felis. Cras dignissim gravida elit, at aliquam metus lobortis ac. Aliquam ac dapibus justo. Vivamus porttitor commodo magna, ut cursus felis imperdiet id. Aenean placerat nisi vitae justo semper, sit amet tristique tellus tempor.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

De acordo com seu problema específico,
**o erro está , simplesmnete, aqui:**

```html
<input type="text" value="codigo" size="25" name="busca">
```

**Substitua por:**

```html
<input type="text" value="codigo" size="25" id="busca">
```

Você colocou `name="busca"`, mas deve ser `id="busca"`.

> Coloquei o exemplo aqui:

https://repl.it/@TaffarelXavier/LatestAustereEfficiency